# Create a 'dragging' element synthetically

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I'm wanting to use the [HTML5 Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) to achieve some drag and drop functionality on my application.

I'm also using FullCalendar, which [unfortunately](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/820) appears to not use the drag and drop API and is instead likely using just mouse click and move events. And at the same time - because the mouse button is still pressed, the mouseover events are blocked.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is being able to drag calendar events to an external source.

So basically my workaround plan is going to be:

1. Let FullCalendar continue using its own methods for doing drag events within the calendar.
2. At the same time, on the `eventDragStart` method synthetically create an element, and create 'dragging' events, that can be detected as `dragover` events by an external element.

Any suggestions for how I would achieve this, or otherwise stop the mouseover event from being blocked?

Here's some example code, note that dragging the pink box triggers the dragover event fine, while dragging the calendar event does not.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const dragEl = document.getElementById("dropzone");
  dragEl.addEventListener("dragenter", () => {
    dragEl.textContent = "dragenter";
  });
  dragEl.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    dragEl.textContent = " I'm the drop zone";
  });
  dragEl.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    dragEl.textContent = "mouseenter";
  });
  dragEl.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    dragEl.textContent = " I'm the drop zone";
  });
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['dayGrid', 'interaction'],
    editable: true,
    events: [{
      title: 'event1',
      start: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString(),
      end: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60).toISOString(),
    }, ],

    eventDragStart: (info) => {
        //Create synthetic event here? 
    },

    eventRender: (info) => {
        //I've tried manually adding 'draggable' attribute, doesn't work. 
    }

  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#dropzone {
  border: solid 3px red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}

#draggable {
  border: solid 3px blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

#html5draggable {
  border: solid 3px pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/interaction/main.min.js"></script>

<div id="dropzone">
  I'm the drop zone
</div>

<div id="html5draggable" draggable="true">
  I'm an HTML5 draggable
</div>

<div id="calendar">

  <div>
```

Comment: I don't know a lot about this topic to be truthful, but have you tried integrating a 3rd-party dragging library into fullCalendar, as described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/third-party-dragging

Comment: @ADyson - Yes I actually did take that approach initially - but it was causing me trouble so I've tried to go for a vanilla solution.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? Seems that dragging can't be faked due to the security model.

Comment: @raarts it's been a while, and I'm not sure about this library specifically, but my approach for drag and drop testing generally - is where possible use a DnD library that also has good keyboard support. It's a lot easier to mock keyboard events, and this should suffice for testing purposes.